# Can´t get the output using jQuery with rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am using jQuery with REST in my application and I want to get the ouput mentioned below using the jQuery within my webpage . 
I used the code below to search by get a company by id (each company has id, name other info supplier and buyers) but the result does not show up for me with my code, any suggestion on what have I missed?

> REST is a concept for HTTP request exchange, so you're making RESTful request calls (e.g. 'get') against the REST-API you implemented on server side.

```
<input name="find" type="text" maxlength="300" id="find"/>
<button onclick="findId()"> Find By ID </button>
    <div id="info"></div>

    <script>
        function findId()
        {
            var id = document.getElementById("find").value;
            $("#info").html("");
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/company/" + id,  function(data)
            {
                for (var i in data) {
                    $('#info').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Other Info: " + data[i].otherInfo + "</p><br>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Supplier: " + data[i].suppliers + "</p><br>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Buyers: " + data[i].buyers + "</p><br>")
                }
            });     
        }
```

When I type `http://localhost:8080/company/` into my browser I get the following output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","otherInfo":"Test 1","suppliers":[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","address":"Test 1","buyers":[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","address":"Test 1"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2","address":"Test 2","buyers":[{"id":3,"name":"Test 3","address":"Test 3"},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2","address":"Test 2"}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2","address":"Test 2","suppliers":[{"id":3,"name":"Test 3","address":"Test 3","buyers":[{"id":4,"name":"Test 4","address":"Test 4"}]}]}]
```

If i type `http://localhost:8080/company/1` into my browser i get

```
{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","otherInfo":"Test 1","suppliers":[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","address":"Test 1","buyers":[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1","address":"Test 1"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2","address":"Test 2","buyers":[{"id":3,"name":"Test 3","address":"Test 3"},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2","address":"Test 2"}]}]}
```

Comment: Why the `java` tag?

Comment: What is the value of `id` in the getJSON call? And what happens if you type that id on the end of the url in your browser? So, if id = 7, what happens if you type http://localhost:8080/company/7 in the browser?

Comment: So are you sure that the value that is being appended to the url is either 1 or 2?

Comment: Java applications don't annoy me. But don't use the `java` tag unless you have a question about Java.

Comment: @propro if your `/company` endpoint returns a list of objects where the largest ID is 4 why do you presume `/7` to work?

Comment: When you add the 1 to the URL (http://localhost:8080/company/1) does it still return an array?  or just a single object?

Comment: Debug using your browser developer tools. What exactly is returned if only one company is requested? if it isn't an array, your loop doesn't make sense. If it is in array, it being an array doesn't make sense.

Comment: try doing console.log(data) before the for loop so as to see what the data object actually looks like.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a cross domain request? If so you can get around it by using jsonp instead of json.

```js
function findId()
        {
            var id = document.getElementById("find").value;
            $("#info").html("");
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/company/?callback=?" + id,  function(data)
            {
                for (var i in data) {
                    $('#info').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Other Info: " + data[i].otherInfo + "</p><br>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Supplier: " + data[i].suppliers + "</p><br>")
                    $('#info').append("<p>Buyers: " + data[i].buyers + "</p><br>")
                }
            });     
        }
```